# Button is working only if radio button is selected

Tags: java, swing, button, selected

I have 3 radio buttons and 1 button. Button should work only if one of this 3 options is selected. How can I use if/else for that? I know that I can use ifSelected but I don't know what should I write later. I'm using Swing.

```
JRadioButton latwy = new JRadioButton("Łatwy");
JRadioButton sredni = new JRadioButton("Średni");
JRadioButton trudny = new JRadioButton("Trudny");

ButtonGroup poziomTrudnosci= new ButtonGroup();
      poziomTrudnosci.add(latwy);
      poziomTrudnosci.add(sredni);
      poziomTrudnosci.add(trudny);


 if(latwy.isSelected() || sredni.isSelected() || trudny.isSelected()) {
      start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {..........} 

            }
}
else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(start, "Select some button.", "blablabla", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

I asked about this because button Start should get action if some radio button is selected. Otherwise you should get statement that you have to select button. This code almost working but only first time get statement. Next time button Start is working normally.

Answer (score 3):

1. Please always show your attempt when asking such questions
2. And show some related and relevant code as well.
3. Give the JRadioButtons ActionListeners that check the state of all the radiobuttons and enables your button if the correct one is selected.
4. As for what to write, a simple single if statement that checks if the pertinent JRadioButton is selected will do.
5. **Edit**: actually just adding an ItemListener on the JRadioButton of interest might be enough -- going to test it now....

---

**Edit**
Yep, it works. Just add an ItemListener on the JRadioButton of interest, and don't even use an if block:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
   testButton.setEnabled(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CheckItemListener extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] RADIOS = {"Fe", "Fi", "Fo", "Fum"};
   private JButton testButton = new JButton("Test");

   public CheckItemListener() {
      ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      for (String radio : RADIOS) {
         JRadioButton rBtn = new JRadioButton(radio);
         add(rBtn);
         buttonGroup.add(rBtn);
         if (radio.equals("Fi")) {
            rBtn.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

               @Override
               public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                  testButton.setEnabled(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
               }
            });
         }
      }
      add(testButton);

      testButton.setEnabled(false);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CheckItemListener mainPanel = new CheckItemListener();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckItemListener");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I know that I should show my code but there is some problem. I'm using other computer and can't do it now. I update post when it will available.

Comment: @user3636661 You will want to not ask questions until you can ask them completely then. Else it makes it very difficult to know where you need help.

Comment: @user3636661 If you meant if ONLY one JRadioButton is selected, you can just add the JRadioButtons to a ButtonGroup to ensure only one is selected, otherwise if you meant that you wanted the JButton to work only if a certain specific JRadioButton was selected, then Hovercraft's answer is what you want.

Comment: @Abdul: no, check this out with code -- my recommendation will work if there are several JRadioButtons are present and added to a single ButtonGroup. The ItemListener is notified if the listened to item's selected state changes, whether or not this occurs due to the JRadioButton being clicked or another JRadioButton being clicked and stealing its selection. Please see example code.